# sorting based on x and y co-ordinate

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to sort a `vector` based on the `x` and `y` co-ordinate . Following is what I have done, but what I want is when I sort based on `x` , I get proper , but when I go for sorting based on `y`, i do not want my `x` order should change.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct item_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    item_t( int h, int w ) : x(h), y(w) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const item_t& gt) {
        os << "(" << gt.x << "," << gt.y << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
typedef std::vector<item_t> item_list_t;
typedef item_list_t::iterator item_list_itr_t;

struct compare_x {
    bool operator ()(const item_t& left, const item_t& rigx) const {
        return left.x < rigx.x;
    }
};
struct compare_y {
    bool operator ()(const item_t& left, const item_t& rigx) const {
        return left.y < rigx.y;
    }
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv) { 
    item_list_t items;

    items.push_back(item_t(15, 176));
    items.push_back(item_t(65, 97));
    items.push_back(item_t(72, 43));
    items.push_back(item_t(102, 6));
    items.push_back(item_t(191, 189));
    items.push_back(item_t(90, 163));
    items.push_back(item_t(44, 168));
    items.push_back(item_t(39, 47));
    items.push_back(item_t(123, 37));

    std::sort( items.begin(), items.end(), compare_x());
    std::copy(items.begin(),items.end(), std::ostream_iterator<item_t>(std::cout," ") );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( items.begin(), items.end(), compare_y());
    std::copy(items.begin(),items.end(), std::ostream_iterator<item_t>(std::cout," ") );

    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

What I want given a set of points orders in increasing order. i.e. `x` and `y` both are increasing.

Comment: can you give an example of the output you are expecting? It is not very clear from the question.

Comment: Firstly you have to decide that what do you expect when `left.x < rigx.x` but `left.y > rigx.y`. In this case what order should they be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do the sort in a single pass:

```
struct compare_xy {
    bool operator ()(const item_t& left, const item_t& right) const {
        return (left.x == right.x ? left.y < right.y : left.x < right.x);
    }
};
```

Comment: If that's what he's looking for (instead of `std::stable_sort`).  In which case, however, in order to respect the order in his description and example, you should compare the `y`s first, not the `x`s.

Comment: What I put matches what I understand of the question - sort first by X, and for matching Xs, sort by Y.

Comment: It is rather difficult to determine what he wants from the question.  I interpreted it to mean sort first by X, then sort by Y, but don't disturb the order when the Y's are equal.  In fact, what he seemed to be asking to me was for a stable sort.  But I'll admit that his question could be interpreted in many ways.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create only one comparator and only one call to `std::sort`:

```
struct compare_xy {
    bool operator ()(const item_t& left, const item_t& right) const {
        return (left.x < right.x) || ((left.x == right.x) && (left.y < right.y));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear to me what you're asking.  If your goal is to
sort by `y`, with `x` determining the order when the `y`'s are equal, 
then a single call to sort with a comparison function:

```
struct OrderYThenX
{
    bool operator()( item_t const& lhs, item_t const& rhs ) const
    {
        return lhs.y < rhs.y
            || (!(rhs.y < lhs.y) && lhs.x < rhs.x);
    }
};
```

This will result in `items` having the same order as it finally has in
your code.

If, as seems more likely from parts of your description and your
example, you want the order between objects with equal `y`s to be
unchanged when you sort by `y`, regardless of how the values were
ordered with respect to `x`, you should use `std::stable_sort`.  Just be
aware that it could be slower than `std::sort`.